# Does Microsoft recommend using Office 64-bit yet?

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

With Office 2010, Microsoft [advised most users to install the 32-bit version as opposed to the 74-bit version](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/enterprise/356173/microsoft-warns-users-off-64-bit-office-2010) as the 64-bit version was incompatible with many add-ins.

Is this still the case with Office 2013, or is installing the 64-bit version finally the recommended course of action from Microsoft?

Comment: Depends on your needs.  If you have a 32-bit Office Add-on that must be used, you have no choice, if you have no needs for an Office add-on then your free to use it.  Microsoft's advice is the same as it always been.

Comment: Not just add-ins, many applications use the Office Automation stuff which I believe requires the same architecture to work.

Comment: *Is it recommended* is not constructive. *Does Microsoft recommend* has a clear-cut answer.

Answer (score 1):

[From this articel from 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/office-frequently-asked-questions-FX102926087.aspx)

> The 32-bit version of Office is installed by default. Even if your
>   computer is running a 64-bit version of Windows, we recommend that you
>   install the 32-bit version of Office, because it is more compatible
>   with the applications and add-ins that work with Office. If you do
>   want to install the 64-bit version of Office, you can do so by taking
>   the following steps: Office 365 Home Premium Preview: Go to
>   www.office.com/myaccount, click Languages and install options, and
>   then click Additional install options. Other Office 365 plans: Log
>   into your account at www.office365.com and choose the option to
>   install the 64-bit version of Office. It is not possible to install
>   both the 64-bit version and 32-bit versions of Office on the same
>   computer.